# phpmyadmin lookup from view

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a lookup for a field in a MySQL table using PHPMyAdmin that holds the GPIO pin numbers for a Rasperry Pi. I have a table that has all of the available pins and I have two tables that list pins in use. I have created a view that shows available pins i.e. pins from the table 'pins' not already used in the two tables. The view works fine but when I try to use that view in the relations 'view' as an internal relation I can chose the view but the field list is unpopulated and when I try to save it, the view is not saved (probably because there was no field to save).

```
select `t1`.`GPIO_Pin` AS `GPIO_Available` 
from (`GPIO_Pins` `t1` 
      left join `qryPinsInUse` `t2` on((`t2`.`GPIO` = `t1`.`GPIO_Pin`))) 
where isnull(`t2`.`GPIO`)
```

[Screenshot of Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq5KQ.jpg)
I can only assume the issue here is a circular reference (or I've made a mistake somewhere!)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: 4.2.12deb2+deb8u2

Comment: This is a version dated 2014-11-20. Can you try on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net with the latest stable version? If there is still a problem, open an issue on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues, attaching a short export of the relevant tables and views' structure.